# Can I use flutterflow widgets on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, widget, flutterflow

My friend and I have designed the frontend of our app on flutterflow. However, there is a limitation when it comes to customizing the functionalities and implementing api on the webpage. Is there anyway I can import the codes in another ide such as vsc with dart and flutter extension. Will the code still run if I do so?

I have copied the login codes from flutterflow into my main function in a new flutter project on vsc and added the dependencies needed but there is a lot of error which I don't know how to fix.
[image]

Comment: Dont't post images, pls paste your relevant and minimal code snippet of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a FlutterFlow user, but I found out that you can export your project from FlutterFlow to github. I typed down "how to export from flutterflow" in YouTube search and I've got quite a few results.

What I can see in the image you've uploaded is that you lack of dependencies (like GoRouter) in pubspec.yaml file. Exporting from FlutterFlow to github, then cloning github project on your computer, then executing `flutter pub get` from command-line, should set up working project.

Comment: I've read that you can only export with paid plans.